# How to implement a JavaFX table with multiple TableViews and Cell Factories?

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have a table whose list of visible items are filtered by radio buttons at the top of the table. So let's say the radio buttons are A, B, C - if A if chosen the table will only show items of type A, if B is chosen it will show only type B, etc.

I create a separate TableView instance for each selection because the users will be interacting with these filtered values in the table and editing values etc. I have a custom cell factory for each column in my table as well because rows need to be highlighted/frozen according to user input.

So:

```
for (all values A.. C) {
    createNewTableView();
}

private void createNewTableView() {
    TableView tableView = new TableView();

    ...
    MyCustomCellFactory customCF = new MyCustomCellFactory();
    customCF.setTableView(tableView);
    clmn1.setCellFactory(customCF);
    ...
}
```

My problem is that when my custom cell factory fires, even through I specifically tell it which instance of table view it belongs to, the table view instance is not the correct one. It's always just the last one I created. I've verified this by checking the instance id's.

So the question is how can I have multiple table view instances with custom cell factories and ensure that I'm always acting on the right one in my custom cell factory code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem actually had to do with not properly instantiating the table columns for each instance of TableView. I posted a simpler example here - [JavaFX tabbed pane with a table view on each tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656895/javafx-tabbed-pane-with-a-table-view-on-each-tab/30657023#30657023) - and got the answer I needed.